# Finding center and rotation angle of ellipse that contains three points

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given three points $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and an ellipse with shape parameters $(a,b)$ (the semi-major and semi-minor), is it possible to determine, if they exist, a center $c \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a rotation angle $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, such that the ellipse centered at $c$ rotated by $\theta$ contains $p_1, p_2, p_3$?

In other words, let
$$E(p, \theta)=\dfrac{(p_x\cos{\theta} + p_{y}\sin{\theta})^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(p_x\sin{\theta} -p_y\cos{\theta})^2}{b^2}$$

I want to determine $c\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, such that:

\begin{equation}
E(p_1-c, \theta) = 1\\
E(p_2-c, \theta) = 1\\
E(p_3-c, \theta) = 1
\end{equation}

Comment: Is it clear to you that the solution for given $a $ and $b $ may be not possible? Moreover this impossibility  will be rather  a rule than exception. Knowing escentrity however should be enough for the construction.

Comment: One of the terms of $E(p,\theta)$ should have a negative sign to it.

Comment: Yes, it is clear that there might not be any solution. What do you mean that it should be a rule? Like, I should include it in the problem statement?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I haven't solve this problem, but I'll provide some hints that may eventually be useful. In the cases where a solution exists, then you can solve it, hopefully, in a step-by-step approach:  1. Use equation for $p_1$ to isolate $c_x$.  2. Substitute $c_x$ in the equation for $p_2$ and solve it for $c_y$.  3. Substitute $c_x$ and $c_y$ in the equation for $p_3$. You will get a large equation with $\sin \theta$  and $\cos \theta$. Hopefully, you may solve that using trigonometric identities.  Have you tried this approach?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I tried going in that direction, but isolating $c_x$ involves solving a quadratic equation, which makes things start getting kinda messy. I tried working out the math, but couldn't isolate $c_x$ and $c_y$ as functions of $\theta$. If you can post at least whatever you have done, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer. I'm going to derive the equations satisfied by the center of desired ellipses. As of this moment,, solving the equations by anything non-numerical is out of reach. The main result is

> The center lies on the intersection of two algebraic curves, one cubic and another quartic.

To avoid conflict with other uses of the variable $a,b$. I will use $\alpha,\beta$ to denote the semi-major/semi-minor axis for the desired ellipse.

---

**main result** - center lies on intersection of a cubic and a quartic curve.

First, let us determine the condition for the origin to be such a center. If $\theta$ is the angle between the semi-major axis with the $x$-axis.The equation of the ellipse will be

$$\begin{align}
& {\small \frac{(x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta)^2}{\alpha^2} + \frac{(-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)^2}{\beta^2} = 1}\\
\iff & {\small \left(\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\alpha^2} + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\beta^2}\right)x^2
+ \left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\alpha^2} + \frac{\cos^2\theta}{\beta^2}\right)y^2 + 
\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{\beta^2}\right)\sin(2\theta)xy = 1}\\
\iff & {\small \frac12\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2} + \frac{1}{\beta^2}\right)(x^2 + y^2)
 + \frac12\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{\beta^2}\right)\left((x^2-y^2)\cos(2\theta) + 2xy\sin(2\theta)\right) = 1 }
\end{align}
$$
Let $\epsilon = \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{\alpha}$ be the eccentricity of the ellipse and define $\sigma$ and $\lambda$ by

$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2} = \frac12\left(\frac1{\alpha^2} + \frac{1}{\beta^2}\right)
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\lambda = \frac{\alpha^2-\beta^2}{\alpha^2+\beta^2} = \frac{\epsilon^2}{2-\epsilon^2}$$

$\sigma$ and $\lambda$ will be an alternative measure of the size and eccentricity of the ellipse. In particular, for the conic above to be an ellipse, we need $0 \le \epsilon < 1 \iff 0 \le \lambda < 1$. In terms of them, above equation becomes

$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(x^2+y^2) - \frac{\lambda}{\sigma^2}\left[(x^2-y^2)\cos(2\theta)+2xy\sin(2\theta)\right] = 1$$

For any $p = (x,y), q = (x', y') \in \mathbb{R}^2$, define

- $\tilde{p} = (-y,x)$, the image of $p$ after a $90^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation.
- $p \cdot q = xx' + y y'\;$ be ordinary 2-d dot product.
- $p \times q \stackrel{def}{=} \tilde{p}\cdot q = x y' - y x'\;$ be the "cross product" for 2-d numbers.
- $U(p) = \begin{bmatrix} x^2 + y^2\\ x^2 - y^2\\ 2xy\end{bmatrix}$
  and $V(p) = U(\tilde{p}) = \begin{bmatrix} x^2 + y^2\\ -x^2 + y^2\\ -2xy\end{bmatrix}$

In terms of them, the equation for 3 points $A,B,C$ to lie on the ellipse centered at origin is

$$\Lambda \cdot U(A) = \Lambda \cdot U(B) = \Lambda U(C) = 1\quad\text{ where }\quad
\Lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
-\lambda\cos(2\theta)\\
-\lambda\sin(2\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
With a little bit of vector algebra, we can solve above three equations to get

$$\Lambda = \frac{U(A)\times U(B) + U(B)\times U(C) + U(C)\times U(A)}{U(A)\cdot (U(B) \times U(C))}$$

It is not hard to verify the $U(\cdot), V(\cdot)$ satisfy following identities

- $U(P)\cdot U(Q) = V(P)\cdot V(Q) = 2(P\cdot Q)^2$.
- $U(P)\cdot V(Q) = V(P)\cdot U(Q) = 2(P\times Q)^2$.
- $U(P)\times U(Q) = 2(P\times Q)\left[V\left(\frac{P+Q}{2}\right)-V\left(\frac{P-Q}{2}\right)\right]$

Using these identities, the denominator simplifies to

$$\small \begin{align} & U(A)\cdot(U(B)\times U(C))\\ 
= & 2(B\times C)\,U(A)\times\left[V\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right) - V\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)\right]\\
= & 2(B\times C)\left[ 2\left(A \times \frac{B+C}{2}\right)^2 - 2\left(A \times \frac{B-C}{2}\right)^2\right]\\
= & -4(B \times C)(C\times A)(A\times B)
\end{align}$$
Let $\Delta$ be the area of $\triangle ABC$ and $u,v,w$ be the barycentric coordinates of the origin with respect to $\triangle ABC$. We have

$$2\Delta u = B \times C,\quad 2\Delta v = C \times A\quad\text{ and }\quad 2\Delta w  = A \times B$$

We find the denominator equals to $-32\Delta^3 uvw$.

Doing similar thing to the numerator and let $D, E, F$ be the midpoint of $BC, CA$ and $AB$, the numerator becomes

$$\small 4\Delta \left[ u (V(D) - V(E-F)) + v(V(E) - V(F-D)) + w(V(F)-V(D-E)) \right]$$
This is a little bit clumsy to write down. Let us use the notation $\sum_{cyc}$ to indicate a cyclic sum of over parameter set 
$$u \to v \to w,\quad A \to B \to C\quad\text{ and }\quad D \to E \to F$$
In this new notation, the equation for $\Lambda$ becomes

$$\Lambda = - \frac{1}{8\Delta^2 uvw} \sum_{cyc} u(V(D) - V(E-F))$$

Switch to other coordinate system where the center, let's call it $Z$, is no longer the origin, the equation for the center becomes

$$\Lambda = -\frac{1}{8\Delta^2 uvw}\sum_{cyc}u(V(Z-D) - V(E-F))\tag{*1}$$

To proceed further, we will do two things.

1. We will switch to a coordinate system where $N$, the [nine-point center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_center) of $\triangle ABC$ is the origin. In this coordinate system, $D,E,F$ will be lying on a circle centered at origin $N$ with radius $\frac{R}{2}$ ($R$ is the circumradius of $\triangle ABC$).
2. We will identify the Euclidean plane with the complex plane, we will use the lower case letter to denote the complex number corresponds to a point. e.g. $Z$ becomes $z$ and $D, E, F$ become $d, e, f$.

After this, we can repress $(*1)$ as two equations

$$\begin{align}
\Lambda_1 = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} 
&= -\frac{1}{8\Delta^2 uvw} \sum_{cyc} u(|z-d|^2 - |e - f|^2)\tag{*2a}\\
\Lambda_2 + i\Lambda_3 = -\frac{\lambda}{\sigma^2} e^{2i\theta}
&= +\frac{1}{8\Delta^2 uvw} \sum_{cyc} u((z-d)^2 - (e - f)^2)\tag{*2b}
\end{align}
$$
Let $o = d + e + f$ (the point corresponding to it is the circumcenter $O$ of $\triangle ABC$) and $u',v',w'$ the barycentric coordinate of $Z$ with respect to $\triangle DEF$. We have 
$$u = \frac{1-u'}{2},\cdots 
\implies  \sum_{cyc} ud = \frac12\sum_{cyc}(1-u')d = \frac12(o-z)$$

Notice
$$\begin{align}
|z-d|^2 - |e-f|^2 &= |z-d|^2 + |e+f|^2 - 2|e|^2 - 2|f|^2\\
&= |z-d|^2+|o-d|^2 - 4|d|^2\\
&= |z|^2 -d(\overline{z+o}) - \bar{d}(z+o) + |o|^2 - 2|d|^2
\end{align}$$

Multiply by $u$ and take cyclic sum, we get

$$\begin{align} \sum_{cyc}u(|z-d|^2 - |e-f|^2)
= & |z|^2 - \frac{(o - z)(\overline{z+o})}{2} - \frac{(\overline{o-z})(z+o)}{2} + |o|^2 - 2|d|^2\\
= & 2|z|^2 - \frac{R^2}{2}\end{align}$$

Equation $(*2a)$ becomes

$$\bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 1em;]{z\bar{z} - \frac{R^2}{4} + \frac{4\Delta^2 uvw}{\sigma^2} = 0} \tag{*3a}$$

Since $u,v,w$ are linear in $(x,y) = (\Re z,\Im z)$. This describe a cubic curve
in the Euclidean plane and it is the locus of the center when the size parameter $\sigma$ is held fixed.

Let $\Omega = \frac{def}{|d|^2} = \frac{4def}{R^2}$. By a similar procedure, we have

$$\begin{align}(z-d)^2 - (e-f)^2
&= (z-d+e+f)(z-d-e-f) = (z-o+2e)(z-o+2f)\\
&= (z-o)^2+2(e+f)(z-o) + 4ef\\
&= z^2 - o^2 - 2d(z-o) + 4\Omega \bar{d}
\end{align}
$$
Multiply by $u$ and take cyclic sum, we get

$$\begin{align}\sum_{cyc} u((z-d)^2 - (e-f)^2)
&= z^2 - o^2 - (o-z)(z-o) + 2\Omega(\bar{o} - \bar{z})\\
&= 2\left(z(z-o) - \Omega(\bar{z} - \bar{o})\right)\end{align}$$

Equations $(*2b)$ becomes

$$z(z-o) - \Omega(\bar{z} - \bar{o}) 
= -\lambda e^{2i\theta}\frac{4\Delta^2 uvw}{\sigma^2}$$

Compare this with equation $(*3a)$, we obtain
$$z(z-o) - \Omega(\bar{z} - \bar{o}) = \lambda e^{2i\theta} \left(z\bar{z} - \frac{R^2}{4}\right)$$
Taking absolute value and square, we obtain a quartic curve
$$\bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 1em]{|z(z-o) - \Omega(\bar{z}-\bar{o})|^2 = \lambda^2 \left|z\bar{z} - \frac{R^2}{4}\right|^2}\tag{*3b}
$$
This is the locus of the center when the eccentricity $\epsilon$ is help fixed.

---

**observation I** - locus for $\sigma$.

1. All locus of $\sigma$ passes through $D,E,F$ and the three foots of $\triangle DEF$.
2. When orthocenter $H$ of $\triangle ABC$ belongs to interior of $\triangle DEF$. $\sigma$ takes a local minimum at $H$. This should corresponds to a special circumellipse associated with $\triangle ABC$. I'm unable to figure out what that is. **Anyone has any idea**?

**observation II** - locus for $\lambda$.

1. When $\epsilon = 0 \implies \lambda = 0$, the locus reduces to a single point $O$. The circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$.
2. When $\epsilon = 1 \implies \lambda = 1$, the quartic terms in Eq. ($*3b$) cancel out. The corresponding curve reduces a union of $3$ lines through the midpoints. i.e. the lines $DE$, $EF$ and $FD$.
3. These $3$ lines split the plane into $7$ regions. When one varies $\epsilon$ (and hence $\lambda$) from $0$ to $1$. The locus sweep across the interior of
   $4$ out of the $7$ regions ( $\triangle DEF$ or the $3$ cone with apex at $D, E, F$). This means in order for a point to be  center for an ellipse, it need to be
   either $D, E, F$ or belongs to the interior of above $4$ regions.
4. Infinitely many loci of $\lambda$ passing through $D, E, F$. Combine with the observation $I_1$, $D, E, F$ are centers for infinitely many circumellipses of $A,B,C$.

---

**To be continued???**

Comment: Impressive effort, but please have a look at my solution. There is a shorter way to a univariate polynomial equation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've seen your answer but I'm more interested in the geometry side of the problem. I want to understand what configuration is possible and how to classify the solutions (either geometrically or topologically).

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, one of the given points is the origin (otherwise, apply a translation).

Let us hypothesize the angle $\theta$. We counter-rotate the three points so that the axis $a$ becomes horizontal. Then we apply an anisotropic dilation of ratio $r:=\dfrac ab$ on the $y$ coordinate. This way, the ellipse becomes a circle of radius $a$, through the origin. The transformation is

$$\begin{cases}p_i=x_i\cos\theta+y_i\sin\theta,\\q_i=r\left(-x_i\sin\theta+y_i\cos\theta\right).\end{cases}$$

The implicit equation of a circle through the origin is

$$\begin{vmatrix}p^2+q^2&p&q\\p_1^2+q_1^2&p_1&q_1\\p_2^2+q_2^2&p_2&q_2\end{vmatrix}=0$$ or

$$\Delta(p^2+q^2)+\Delta_p p+\Delta_q q=0$$ 
where the deltas are minors.

By completing the square,

$$\left(p-\frac{\Delta_p}{2\Delta}\right)^2+\left(q-\frac{\Delta_q}{2\Delta}\right)^2=\frac{\Delta_p^2+\Delta_q^2}{4\Delta^2}$$ and in this expression the RHS is the squared radius.

By equating to $a^2$,

$$(q_1(p_2^2+q_2^2)-q_2(p_1^2+q_1^2))^2+(p_1(p_2^2+q_2^2)-p_2(p_1^2+q_1^2))^2=4a^2(p_1q_2-p_2q_1)^2.$$

Unfortunately, this expands to a big sextic polynomial in $\cos\theta,\sin\theta$ and I don't foresee a nice simplification.

---

Note that you can rationalize the last equation by

$$\begin{cases}\cos\theta=\dfrac{t^2-1}{t^2+1},\\\sin\theta=\dfrac{2t}{t^2+1}\end{cases}$$

and you will end up with a univariate polynomial of degree $12$. But by symmetry, if $\theta$ is a solution, so is $\theta+\pi$ and the $t$ solutions will come in pairs $t\,t'=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the three points be $A,B,C$.  The idea of this solution is to transform $\triangle ABC$ into an equilateral triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) $

There are three possible arrangements for the vertices in terms of the pre-images of the equilateral triangle vertices:

$A , B , C$

$A , C , B$

$B , C , A$

The affine transformation is

$f(P) = T (p - V_1)$

where $V_1$ is the first vertex.

Take for example the first arrangement, then

$ T \begin{pmatrix} B- A && C - A \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 && \dfrac{1}{2} \\ 0 && \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{pmatrix} $

From which, we can calculate the transformation matrix $T$.

Now, we'll pass an ellipse in standard orientation through the three vertices of the equilateral triangle, let the center of the ellipse be $ C = (1/2 , c )$, then the equation of ellipse

$ \dfrac{(x - (1/2))^2}{ a^2 } + \dfrac{(y - c)^2} {b^2} = 1 $

The points through which this ellipse passes are $(0,0), (1,0), (\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} ) $

Substituting the first is the same as substituting the second, they both give us

$ \dfrac{1}{4 a^2} + \dfrac{c^2}{ b^2} = 1 $

Substituting the third point,

$ \dfrac{ (\sqrt(3)/2 - c ) ^2}{  b^2 }= 1 $

So that  $ b = sqrt(3)/2 - c $

Now define the matrix

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{a^2} &&   0 \\ 0  && \dfrac{1}{b^2} \end{bmatrix}$

The pre-transformation Q is obtained as follows:

The position vectors are related by $r = T (r' - A)$  where $r'$ is the position vector of the original points, and $r$ is the position vector after applying the transformation.

Now, we have the ellipse that passes through the three vertices of the equilateral triangle is given by

$ (r - C)^T Q (r - C) = 1 $

where $C = (1/2, c )$

Substitute $r$

$(T (r' - A) - C )^T Q (T (r' - A) - C) = 1 $

And this simplifies to

$ (r' - A - T^{-1} C ) ^T T^T Q T ( r' - A - T^{-1} C ) = 1 $

so our $Q' = T^T Q T$

Expanding,

$Q' = \begin{bmatrix} (1/a^2) t_1^2 + (1/b^2) t_3^2 &&     (1/a^2) t_1 t_2 +(1/b^2) t_3 t_4 \\(1/a^2) t_1 t_2 +(1/b^2) t_3 t_4 && (1/a^2) t_2^2 + (1/b^2) t_4^2 \end{bmatrix} $

where $T = \begin{bmatrix} t_1 && t_2 \\ t_3 && t_4 \end{bmatrix} $

we want the eigenvalues of $Q'$ to be $ 1/a_e^2 $ and $  1/b_e^2 $ where $a_e, b_e$ are the given semi-axes lengths of the ellipse.

so using the trace and the determinant, we obtain

$ \dfrac{1}{a^2} (t_1^2 + t_2^2) + \dfrac{1}{b^2} (t_3^2 + t_4^2 ) = \dfrac{1}{a_e^2} + \dfrac{1}{b_e^2} \hspace{30pt}(1) $

and for the determinant expression, it simplifies to

$ \dfrac{1}{a b} | t_1 t_4 - t_2 t_3 | = \dfrac{1}{a_e b_e} \hspace{30pt} (2) $

Now recall that

$ \dfrac{1}{4 a^2} + \dfrac{c^2}{ b^2} = 1 $

and that

$ c = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - b $

substituting this last equation in the previous one, gives

$ \dfrac{1}{4 a^2} + \dfrac{3}{4 b^2} - \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{b} = 0 \hspace{30pt}(3)$

This system of equations $(1), (2), (3)$ in the two unknowns $a , b$ is overdetermined.  So the strategy to solve it is to solve $(1), (2)$ and then check that $(3)$ is satisfied.  Once all three equations are satisified then we have our ellipse, and we can compute the center and the $Q'$ matrix from which by diagonalizing we can compute $\theta $.